# Docker Desktop not starting - Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: docker, windows-10, hyper-v, docker-desktop

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Edition: Professional

Id: 1903

Build: 18362

BuildLabName: 18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

After Docker Desktop has been installed successfully, if I try to run it, it fails with the below error

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.WPF.BackendClient.Version()
   at Docker.WPF.BackendClient.CheckVersion()
   at Docker.WPF.BackendClient.CheckService(String action)
   at Docker.WPF.BackendClient.SendMessage(String action, Object[] parameters)
   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

I have ensured that CFG Override is unchecked for vmcompute.exe but it still does not work.

Note: I am using a Surface Laptop and my ProgramData is located in the microSD Card (not on the SSD)
The ProgramData has been shifted to D: by mklink /XJ command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @abu-ahmed-al-khatiri I ran the clean script after uninstalling and ensured that the AppData and ProgramData folders for Docker and Docker Desktop are deleted and the computer is restarted before reinstalling.

The issue then was : Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\Docker\cli-plugins' is denied.
**I gave "Everyone" the "Full Control" on the folder D:\ProgramData\Docker.**

Then the issue was : Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop.userprofiles is denied.
**I gave "Everyone" the "Full Control" on the folder D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop.**

DockerDesktop is now running

Answer (score 8):

After a lot of tries, my solution was as below, as can be found here (answer by jagraj):
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3597

1. Open "Window Security"
2. Open "App & Browser control"
3. Click "Exploit protection settings" at the bottom
4. Switch to "Program settings" tab
5. Locate "C:\WINDOWS\System32\vmcompute.exe" in the list and expand it
6. Click "Edit"
7. Scroll down to "Code flow guard (CFG)" and uncheck
   "Override system settings"
8. Start vmcompute from powershell "net start vmcompute"

Answer (score 1):

Try to cleaning settings after uninstall.

Remove :
1. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Docker
2. C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Docker
3. C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ran the clean script after uninstalling and ensured that the above mentioned folders are deleted and the computer is restarted before reinstalling.

The the issue was : Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\Docker\cli-plugins' is denied.

I gave "Everyone" the "Full Control" on that folder.

Then the issue was : Access to the path 'D:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\.userprofiles is denied.

I gave "Everyone" the "Full Control" on that folder as well.

DockerDesktop is not running